# How to receive a json to insert

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am receiving some values per post and I have a json type field but it arrives empty and if I enter a normal text it works and I do not see the error in the field

the model was updated so that it receives the fields and allows inserting in mysql

```
POSTman

    {
      "Code":"1234",//it works
      "Desc":"desc",//it works
      "Config":{"link":"https://stackoverflow.com/"  }, //not works
      "Dev":[ {"item":1},{"item":2}]//not works
       
    }
    
    
    type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Code   string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
        Desc   string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
        Config JSON   `json:"currencies" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
        Dev   JSON     `json:"currencies" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
    }
    
    func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {
         var usuario models.User
    var bodyBytes []byte
    if c.Request.Body != nil {
        bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    }
    data := bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)
    fmt.Println(data.Config)

         c.BindJSON(&usuario)
         db.DB.Create(&usuario)
        c.JSON(200, usuario)
    }
```

Model update.  receive post form with json fields and insert in mysql

```
package models

import (
    "bytes"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "errors"
)

type JSON []byte

func (j JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if j.IsNull() {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return string(j), nil
}
func (j *JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        *j = nil
        return nil
    }
    s, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        errors.New("error")
    }
    *j = append((*j)[0:0], s...)
    return nil
}
func (m JSON) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if m == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return m, nil
}
func (m *JSON) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if m == nil {
        return errors.New("error")
    }
    *m = append((*m)[0:0], data...)
    return nil
}
func (j JSON) IsNull() bool {
    return len(j) == 0 || string(j) == "null"
}
func (j JSON) Equals(j1 JSON) bool {
    return bytes.Equal([]byte(j), []byte(j1))
}
```

Thank you very much to everyone who helped me, I consider that the functionality of receiving a json and saving it in mysql is very common and this can be useful to many people

Comment: `c.BindJSON(...)` returns an error you need to capture it and handle it; Also the json lib will not automatically parse the nested json structure to string directly

Comment: It is obvious from your Postman example that `Config` and `Dev` fields are not strings, so that is the first thing you will have to change in your model. Next, what does your `users` or `user` table look like, and how `Config` and `Dev` fields relate to it?

Comment: Hi, update the model, I only get this []

Answer (score 0):

You can change the JSON like below or You can change the Struct like below (*I prefer struct approach*)

```
{
"Code": "1234",
"Desc": "desc",
"Config": {
   "Link": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
},
"Dev": [
   {
      "Item": 1
   },
   {
      "Item": 2
   }
 ]
}
```

Struct:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code   string `json:"Code" gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
    Desc   string `json:"Desc" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
    Config []struct {
        Link  string `json:"link" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
        Title string `json:"title" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
    }
    Dev []struct {
        Item string `json:"item" gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Satz, thanks the struct if perfect, what I have not been able to is receive that json and save it in a mysql fields called two config and dev, is where I am stuck

Comment: Ok, I got it. Your JSON is not matching with the given struct. Item should be string but you are passing int. Please find this link, I have added working code. https://play.golang.org/p/jsfFmtcjjKB

Comment: Hi @Satz    I don't understand why I always get Config: null dev:null,  field config []struct{"Link string "json:\"Link\"  gorm:\"type:varchar(255);\""; "Linktest string "json:\"Linktest\"  gorm:\"type:varchar(255);\""} cannot convert application.config,
I receive this by post

Comment: Please make sure you are passing correct string literals. I could see some escape characters in your json. Did you tried above link?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, what I did is receive the body and I have it complete, but what I have not been able to do is access an element of it,   
  fmt.Println(data.config)

Answer (score 0):

You have made two kind of mistakes

1. Your json decoding cannot work because your struct does not match your json. `Config` is defined as a array of something but in your json you have an object not array, and in `Dev` the property `Item` is a int not a string
2. Your model may not be well defined as you have not defined you joined table. Well I never seen a working example with this kind of definition. I suggest you to declare your nested struct as independent struct.

Here a full working example :

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

const data = `{
    "Code":"1234",
    "Desc":"desc",
    "Config":{"link":"https://stackoverflow.com/"  },
    "Dev":[ {"item":1},{"item":2}] 
}`

type Config struct {
    Id     int    `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Link   string `json:"link"`
    Title  string
    UserId int
}
type Item struct {
    Id     int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Item   int `json:"item"`
    UserId int
}
type User struct {
    Id     int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Code   string
    Desc   string
    Config Config `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId"`
    Dev    []Item `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId"`
}

func initDb(url string) (*gorm.DB, *sql.DB, error) {
    connexion := sqlite.Open(url)
    db, err := gorm.Open(connexion, &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    sql, err := db.DB()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Item{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    return db, sql, nil

}

func run() error {
    db, sql, err := initDb("file::memory:?cache=shared")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer sql.Close()

    var user User
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &user)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", user)
    err = db.Create(&user).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var loaded User
    db.Preload("Config").Preload("Dev").First(&loaded)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", loaded)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- try adding this JSON Field in your model

```
import (
    "errors"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
)

// JSON Interface for JSON Field of yourTableName Table
type JSON interface{}

// Value Marshal
func (a JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(a)
}

// Scan Unmarshal
func (a *JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b,&a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**All these answers didn't work for me, but this will work for everyone**

Model

```
// This is the max Thing you need
import "gorm.io/datatypes"
import "encoding/json"

type CMSGenericModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    //... Other Posts
    ExtraData   datatypes.JSON `json:"data"`
}
```

In Handler Function

```
type CmsReqBody struct {
    // ============= RAW ========
    Data        json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
    // other props...
}

cmsBodyRecord := new(models.CMSGenericModel)
cmsBodyPayload := new(CmsReqBody)

if err := c.BodyParser(cmsBodyPayload); err != nil {
    return c.Status(503).SendString(err.Error())
}


cmsBodyRecord.ExtraData = datatypes.JSON(cmsBodyPayload.Data)
```

My Sample Data

```
{
  "title": "Blog Post 1",
  "subtitle": "first",
  "description": "Updated",
  "type": "blog",
  "isActive": true,
  "uuid": "new",
  "data": {
    "complex1": ["kkkk", "yyyy"],
    "complex2": [
      {
        "name": "sourav"
      },
      {
        "name": "yahooo"
      },
      {
        "yahoo": "name",
        "kjk": ["abbsb", {"data": "abcd"}]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```